# Need help searching for a value in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firestore and I'm making a register page with vue. 
Before a new user is made, it has to check if the given username already exists or not and if not, make a new user.

I can add a new user to the database, but I don't know how to check if the username already exists or not. I tried a lot of things and this is the closest I've gotten:

```
db.collection("Users")
           .get()
           .then(querySnapshot => {
             querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
               if (this.username === doc.data().username) {
                 usernameExist = true;                              
               }
             });
           });
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Link to documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

You can `where` this query, which is beneficial to you in multiple ways:

1: Fewer docs pulled back = fewer reads = lower cost to you.

2: Less work on the client side = better performance.

So how do we `where` it? Easy.

```js
db.collection("Users")
           .where("username", "==", this.username)
           .get()
           .then(querySnapshot => {
             //Change suggested by Frank van Puffelen (https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)
             //querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
             //  if (this.username === doc.data().username) {
             //    usernameExist = true;                              
             //  }
             //});
             usernameExists = !querySnapshot.empty 
           });
```

Comment: You can replace the loop and `if` check with a simpler `if (!querySnapshot.empty) { usernameExists = true }`.

Comment: That's a really good suggestion. I'm going to update my answer with that. Thank you!