# Firebase loop through the fields with autoid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a booking application in React.js where the user choose a date and time and i want to compare my states with the database data if the date and time already exists? if no write it to db if yes write an alert "You can't book this time"
How to loop through the fields in firestore with autoid? collection/${autoid}/field and compare each field with the state which i receive.

```
writetodb = props => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const userid = this.props.user.uid;
    const username = this.props.user.email;
    const time = this.state.startTime;
    const date = this.state.startDate;
      var docRef = db.collection(`appointment/${autoid}/field`);
      docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
              console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              // if (doc.data() == time){
              //
              // }
          } else {
              console.log("No such document!");
              db.collection("appointment")
                .add({
                  time: time,
                  date: date,
                  id: userid,
                  name: username,
                  approved: false
                })
          }
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to search for a document with a specific field value, is that right?

Comment: yes with date and time

Comment: Ah. Well then see my answer here. Don't think vue vs react matters in this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341540/need-help-searching-for-a-value-in-firestore/60341746#60341746

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help searching for a value in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341540/need-help-searching-for-a-value-in-firestore)